# Privileged command as part of cronjob

Tags: cron

I have a personal username/password on a unix machine with limited privileges. Whenever I need  to execute some commands I have to substitute user using the **su** command, then I execute it normally.

Now, I need to add a cronjob that uses such privileged commands so I added the cronjob on the crontab of the user I substituted to in order to have access to these commands.

Strangely, it turned out to me that these commands fail to run for some reason as a cronjob although when I execute them directly from shell (after su) they work seamlessly.

Why does this happen? Why do these commands not work as part of cronjobs?

Answer (score 2):

They probably expect some environment variable to be set somehow, but it isn't when the command is run directly as that user. Usually `$PATH`.

Comment: I'm... not really sure how you want me to elaborate. Look at your environment variables. See if they matter.

Answer (score 1):

I would add an output file to your cron entry so you can see why it failed to execute. i.e:

```
*/5 * * * *   path_to_script.sh > /tmp/myscript.out 2>&1
```

After 5 minutes, check /tmp/myscript.out and see what it's complaining about.

Of course it would help finding out if you have the permission to create crons in the first place.